# Lombok getter setter cannot find symbol

Tags: java, lombok

I'm using Intellij and trying to apply lombok to the project.
But it keeps saying "cannot find symbol".
Here's a quick sample of my code.

Class

```
import lombok.*;

@Data
public class Product {

    private String name;
    private Integer price;

    public Product(String name, Integer price){
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Main

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class CollectionMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Collection<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        Product door = new Product("DOOR",90);
        Product bed = new Product("BED",60);
        Product ipad = new Product("iPad",15);

        products.add(door);
        products.add(bed);
        products.add(ipad);

        final Iterator<Product> productIterator = products.iterator();

        while(productIterator.hasNext()){
            Product product = productIterator.next();
            System.out.println(product.getPrice());
        }

    }
}
```

and the error says

CollectionMain.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.println(product.getPrice());
                                      ^
  symbol:   method getPrice()
  location: variable product of type Product

I have enabled the annotation processor
[image]

plugin

[image]

Comment: Did you install the Lombok plugin in IntelliJ itself?

Comment: yes, i did. will attach the screenshot

Comment: Just checking the annotation processor box worked for me

Answer (score 21):

I didn't put

```
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
```

in my build.gradle

problem solved.

Comment: Note to myself: both `annotationProcessor` and `implementation` declaration are necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. But my solution was bit different.

My project is on java 8 but IDEA SDK was set to java 17. Once I changed it to java 8 issue was solved.

1. Go to File > Project Structure > Project
2. Change SDK
   [image]
3. Apply > OK
4. File > Invalidate and Restart

Comment: damn my project IS java 17 :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you did the correct configuration and IDE setting is correct(Enable annotation procession)
[image]

and Other settings are correct then you can add following in to the pom.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        
        
          <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                       ..........................
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                            </path>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                
          </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the Maven repository only provides you with the 'compileOnly' dependency for the Gradle builder.
However, if you look in the Lombok documentation you will find that you also need to use the 'annotationProcessor'.

https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error when tried to build my project (gradle). I used jdk-15 on my project, but then installed jdk-17 on my computer (even without changing sdk in the project) and the problem happened.
To fix the issue I uninstalled jdk-17 from the computer (deleting sdk on project is not enough)

Answer (score 0):

Added both compile only and annotationProcessor
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1L04.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34456604)

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to use the Lombok Gradle plugin as stated in the [Lombok installation guide for Gradle](https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle):

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '8.3'
}
```